# In Wordpress using a custom Timber/Twig theme how can I fetch .env variables in a twig file?

Tags: wordpress, environment-variables, twig, timber

As the title says. I have a custom theme that is using timber plugin so has twig for its templates. But I am not sure how to fetch data from the env file to use in a twig file.

Comment: I think you are just looking at the problem from a wrong angle, you just need to pass env var to the twig template from the PHP file which is calling the twig->render function =)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would globally access the ENV variables from twig templates.

I'm not sure if this would be a security flaw but I don't think a user can access the twig context (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

```
<?php
    
    class Site extends TimberSite {
        function __construct() {
            /**
             * Load composer dependencies
             */
            $composer_autoload = __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
            if ( file_exists( $composer_autoload ) ) require_once $composer_autoload;
    
            /**
             * Load global ENV variables
             */
            $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable( ABSPATH . '/..' );
            $dotenv->load();
        
    
            add_filter( 'timber_context', [ $this, 'add_to_context' ] );
    
            parent::__construct();
        }
    
        function add_to_context( $context ) {
    
            /**
             * Load environment variables in twig
             */
            $context['env'] = $_ENV;
  
    
            return $context;
        }
    }
    
    new Site();
```

You could then use them like so:

```
<script>
   window.stripe = Stripe('{{ env['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY'] }}');
</script>
```